# Registrar venta con su detalle venta mediante transacciones en un stored procedure MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedure, transacciones

Estoy intentando registrar 2 tablas mediante transacciones en MySQL y tengo una tabla `VENTA`, a la que puse como PK el campo `id_venta` y es de tipo `int` autoincrement, ademas tengo la tabla `DETALLE_VENTA`, que tiene como FK el campo `id_venta` de tipo `int` y que hace referencia al mismo campo de la tabla `VENTA`.

Ahora bien no tengo problemas al momento de registrar la venta en diferentes procedimientos almacenados sin transacciones, el detalle es que he estado leyendo en internet que lo ideal sería que el proceso de la venta se realice mediante una transacción en un solo SP recuperando el `id_venta` con la función `LAST_INSERT_ID` de mysql y en seguida registrar el detalle de la venta (todos los productos que incluye esa venta) para que sea más segura, porque en caso que exista algún error en la venta el detalle ya no se registra y no afectaría a ninguna tabla.

En los foros me dijeron para guardar la cabecera de la venta y luego traer este dato a través de una consulta (por ej. `select max(id_venta) from venta`) pero creo que si en caso de que otra terminal inserta registro en la base de datos al mismo tiempo, podría encontrarme con grandes problemas y ademas que no le veo eficiente.

Agradeceré infinitamente por la ayuda, saludos cordiales.

Comment: Esta tarea, ¿quieres que se realice con un "STORED PROCEDURE" en MySQL, o todo el trabajo lo hará la aplicación y sólo se enviarán los datos ya procesados para ser guardados en MySQL?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que todo los insert se realicen en el procedimiento almacenado de mysql. Los datos solo enviarlos desde la aplicación y que el procedimiento los procese.

Comment: He estado pensando en tu pregunta, y creo que lo más conveniente sería manejar la transacción en el Front-End, por las siguientes razones: 1. No sabes *a priori* cuántos productos tendrá cada venta (a menos que los almacenes de alguna manera en una tabla temporal en el servidor). 2. Puedes hacer transacciones directamente en el Front-End (en C# puedes usar `using(MysqlTransaction tr=con.BeginTransaction()) {/*...*/ tr.commit();} catch(Exception e){trans.rollback();}`

Answer (score 1):

desde el lenguaje de programacion en un metodo envias la cabecera, con el procedimiento almacenado ups_venta_insertar, este retornara el idventa y entonces recorres la grilla donde tienes las lineas que componen el detalle de la venta y envias al otro procedimiento almacenado ups_venta_detalle_insertar:

```
-- CABECERA VENTA (tabla venta)

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `usp_venta_insertar`(
IN `p_fecha` datetime,
IN `p_id_cliente` int(10) UNSIGNED,
IN `p_subtotal` decimal,
IN `p_descuentos` decimal,
IN `p_total` decimal,
OUT `p_idventa` int(11) UNSIGNED,
OUT `p_mierror_cod` int(11),
OUT `p_mierror_msg`  text)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
COMMENT 'Insertar Venta'
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
BEGIN

ROLLBACK;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @RETURNED_SQLSTATE = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @MYSQL_ERRNO = MYSQL_ERRNO, @MESSAGE_TEXT = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SET p_mierror_cod = -10;
    SET p_mierror_msg = CONCAT("ERRNO: ",@MYSQL_ERRNO, ", SQLSTATE: ", @RETURNED_SQLSTATE, ", TEXT: ", @MESSAGE_TEXT);

END;

START TRANSACTION;

    SET p_idventa = 0;

    INSERT INTO `venta` (`id_cliente`, `subtotal`, `descuentos`, `total`)
      VALUES (`p_id_cliente`, `p_subtotal`, `p_descuentos`, `p_total`);

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO p_idventa;

     -- Exitosamente
    SET p_mierror_cod = 1;
    SET p_mierror_msg = 'Venta insertado correctamente';

COMMIT;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

-- LINEA VENTA (TABLA venta_detalle)
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `usp_venta_detalle_insertar`(
IN `p_id_venta` int(10) UNSIGNED,
IN `p_id_producto` int(10) UNSIGNED,
IN `p_cantidad` int,
IN `p_precio_unitario` decimal,
IN `p_importe` decimal,
OUT `p_idventa_detalle` int(11) UNSIGNED,
OUT `p_mierror_cod` int(11),
OUT `p_mierror_msg`  text)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
COMMENT 'Insertar Venta Detalle (linea)'
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
BEGIN

ROLLBACK;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @RETURNED_SQLSTATE = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @MYSQL_ERRNO = MYSQL_ERRNO, @MESSAGE_TEXT = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SET p_mierror_cod = -10;
    SET p_mierror_msg = CONCAT("ERRNO: ",@MYSQL_ERRNO, ", SQLSTATE: ", @RETURNED_SQLSTATE, ", TEXT: ", @MESSAGE_TEXT);

END;

START TRANSACTION;

    SET p_idventa_detalle = 0;

    INSERT INTO `venta_detalle` (`id_venta`, `id_producto`,`cantidad`,`precio_unitario`,`importe`)
      VALUES (`p_id_venta`,`p_id_producto`,`p_cantidad`,`p_precio_unitario`,`p_importe`);

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO p_idventa_detalle;

     -- Exitosamente
    SET p_mierror_cod = 1;
    SET p_mierror_msg = 'Venta Detalle (Linea) insertado correctamente';

COMMIT;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenos días Juan!

Otro usuario comentaba que podés hacer esto en el front-end dado que no sabés, a priori, cuántos y qué productos tendrá la venta. Si te es posible, describí más detalladamente tu escenario para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Por ejemplo, en el momento en que se abre la ventana para nueva venta podés insertar una nueva fila en la tabla venta y establecerla en un estado especial para saber que esa venta está en "Armado". Entonces, en la aplicación almacenás el ID de la venta y en el momento en que un usuario agrega un nuevo producto al detalle entonces enviás el ID de la venta e insertás el detalle en venta_detalle. El estado te va a servir para estar resguardado ante un corte de luz por ejemplo, entonces podrás recuperar las ventas que tienen stock reservado y que todavía no se habían confirmado.

El código crítico estará en la asignación al detalle de la venta y la baja del stock. De esa forma, si varios vendedores están haciendo ventas en tu sistema nunca se "pisarán" el stock, porque si uno agrega a su venta X cantidad de un artículo entonces otro vendedor ya va a ver 0 de stock y no lo va a poder agregar a la venta. En cambio, si lo hacés todo en un mismo procedimiento almacenado vas a enviar el detalle una vez que la venta ya esté armada, pero en el lapso en que los vendedores arman la venta tu base podría quedar inconsistente. Por ejemplo, vendedor A agrega 2 unidades del producto X porque el stock es 2, antes de que el vendedor A presione en guardar venta el vendedor B agrega 1 unidad del mismo producto X porque el stock sigue siendo 2. El que primero de en Guardar habrá tomado el stock mientras que el otro recibirá un error. Es preferible no permitir agregar el artículo si el stock es menor a la cantidad a agregar. Una vez que el artículo se agregó a la venta el stock queda reservado.

Por otro lado, los datos en un parámetro al hacer la llamada del stored procedure de MySQL los podrías enviar como array (en PostgreSQL lo he probado). De esa forma podrías enviar varios IDs, cantidades, etc, en un mismo parámetro y en la base de datos ir recorriendo para hacer los inserts en una transacción como pensabas.

Espero haber sido de ayuda! Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

He realizado procesos como estos, y lo más conveniente ha sido enviar un archivo xml con la cabecera y el detalle a un solo SP en el cual están ambos INSERTS dentro de una transacción. Lo he hecho en SQL Server, me imagino que en MySQL también se debería poder hacer.
Saludos.

Comment: ¿Algún ejemplo que aportar para que el _OP_ entienda lo que describes?

Comment: Comparto un enlace que será de mucha ayuda. http://www.elguille.info/colabora/NET2006/sebaconte_UtilizacionCabeceraDetalle.htm

Comment: Sería buena idea poner los detalles relevantes de dicho link en la respuesta, para que si un día el link ya no está, la respuesta aún sea válida.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría usar un código único solo que tienes que hacer antes de tu registro en la tabla VENTA un:

```
 SELECT UUID() INTO @codigo_unico;
```

Que tendrás que guardarlo dentro de un campo tipo char o varchar, así te evitas el problema del que el número del id se repita. o lo utilice otro. 
Este código único lo usaras en VENTA y será la FK en DETALLE_VENTA.
Si necesitas mas seguridad en el proceso, deberás usar START TRANSACTION. y todo lo que conlleva.